# How to pass external object list and form object in ajax to mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, form-submit, ajaxform

I am going to pass external object list with form-data in submitHandler section. When i am passing form object only it is working properly. but i want to add list of object to that ajax post request.
  JS

```
submitHandler: function (e) {

                $(".loader-showhide").show();

                var contacts = [
                    { name: 'test 1', mobile: '11111111' },
                    { name: 'test 2', mobile: '22222222' }
                ];

                var dataToPost = JSON.stringify({ contacts: contacts });
                var form = $(e);
                form.find(":submit").attr("disabled", true);

                $.ajax(form.attr("action"),
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: { model: $(form).serialize(), contacts: dataToPost },
                        cache: false,
                        success(data) {
                            $(".loader-showhide").hide();
                            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                            var table = $('#dt_account').DataTable();
                            table.ajax.reload();
                            toastr.success('Successfully added.');
                            $('#submitBtn').prop("disabled", false);
                        },
                        error(xhr) {

                        }
                    });
            }
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ActivityViewModel model, List<Contact> contacts)
    {
        try
        {
            int result = 0;
            return Json(new { StatusCode = result });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Object

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my form, I used jquery datatable and jquery form submit with submit handler.

```
                    <form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Activity")" id="account-form"  method="POST" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-blocker-wrap">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Id)
                            <div class="card-block row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="scroller bottom-box px-3">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-5 px-4 border-right">
                                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                                    <label asp-for="Name">Activity Name</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Name, new { maxlength = 100, placeholder = "Campaign Name", @class = "form-control", required = "true" })
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                                    <label asp-for="StartDateTime">Start Date</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.StartDateTime, new { type = "date", maxlength = 100, placeholder = "Start Date", @class = "form-control", required = "true" })
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                                    <label asp-for="EndDateTime">End Date</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.EndDateTime, new { type = "date", maxlength = 100, placeholder = "End Date", @class = "form-control", required = "true" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-5 px-4 border-right">
                                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                                    <label asp-for="ContactType">Select Method</label><br />
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.ContactType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.ContactList, new { maxlength = 100, placeholder = "Campaign Name", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "ChangeMethod(this)", required = "true" })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 py-5 px-4 border-right">
                                                <div disabled class="col-md-6 grl-section">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">

                                                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.GRLContactGroupList.Count(); i++)
                                                        {
                                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.GRLContactGroupList[i].IsChecked) @(@Model.GRLContactGroupList[i].GroupName + " - " + @Model.GRLContactGroupList[i].ZONE) <br />

                                                            @for (int j = 0; j < Model.GRLContactGroupList[i].GRLContactList.Count(); j++)
                                                            {
                                                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.GRLContactGroupList[i].GRLContactList[j].IsChecked) @Model.GRLContactGroupList[i].GRLContactList[j].Name <br />

                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-footer modal-footer py-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 px-4">
                                    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default color-theme">Clear</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: First I see Missused of ViewModel pattern  to declare a proper List<GRLContactGroupList> in a ViewModel to type your view.